# Zend Framwork Not routing error

Tags: ssl, routes, ssl-certificate

The requested URL could not be matched by routing.

I want to add SSL certificate I have created both folders but not able to access below Path. Please tell me where I can add permission.

```
www.xyz.com/.well-known/pki-validation/sample.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this `rm -rf  /home/MYUSERNAME/public_html/example.com/.well-known`

Comment: I  have created that folder in public but its not showing hidden